Weird definition of discrete random variable - How do you define a sum over an uncountable set?
After this huge eye opener Discrete Random Variables May Have Uncountable Images (cf 'Discrete Random Variables May Have Uncountable Images' - 'Almost surely countable'?) I checked my probability textbooks on their definitions of discrete random variable
From Rosenthal - A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory



Translating this to random variables, I guess it's saying...
Let $X$ be a random variable.
(
To relate to laws I guess :

Let $\mathscr B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ or however it's called - I forgot. Then its law is $L_X:\mathscr B \to \mathbb R$, $L_X(B):=P(X \in B)$.

And then any Borel 'probability' measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ is any measure on the measurable space $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B)$ w/ $\mu(\mathbb R)=1$. And then $\mu$ is actually the law of some random variable $X$ in some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$


)

$X$ is discrete if $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} P(X=x) = P(X \in \mathbb R)$,

or in law language

$X$ is discrete if $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} L_X(x) = L_X(\mathbb R)$,

where I guess we might view the event $ \{ X \in \mathbb R \} $ as $\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R} \{ X = x \}$ to show countable additivity or something.
And then the exercise is an equivalent definition is

There is a countable set $S \subseteq \text{im}(X) \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $P(X \in S) = 1$ i.e. $P(X \notin S) = 0$.

or in law language

There is a countable set $S \subseteq \text{im}(X) \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $L_X(S) = 1$ i.e. $L_X(S^C) = 0$.

Question : But the initial definition is kinda weird since you can sum over a countable set only right?

I imagine it's defined somewhere else in the book, but in any case taking the infinite sum to be the supremum of all finite sums is a fine definition. Of course this only makes sense for sums of nonnegative numbers.

That's good catch. Author doesn't define sum over any set except ordered as natural numbers. I think when all elements are non-negative, something like $\sum\limits_{x\in S} x = \sup\limits_{S' \subseteq S, |S'| < \infty} \sum\limits_{x \in S'} x$ is assumed. And then it's reasonable exercise to prove that if this $\sup$ is finite then it has at most countably many non-zero elements.

@D.Brogan thanks is that the same as what mihaild said?

@mihaild 1- thanks is that the same as what D.Brogan said? 2- so then there's no need for the exercise in the book if you already do the exercise you said right?

@BCLC 1. Yes. 2. Exercise in the book is essentially the same as I wrote.

This usually requires some discussion because it's not a part of usual sum definitions from calculus that everyone knows, but you can sum nonnegative values over uncountable sets by defining $$\sum\limits_{x \in S} P(x) = \sup \left\{ \sum\limits_{x \in I} P(x) \,\middle|\, I \subset S, I \text{ finite}\right\}$$
Rosenthal notes this in passing in §1.2:



